# Closing LibreOffice causes logout 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, logout

When closing any LibreOffice application, it causes an automatic logout, taking me to a black screen first then to the login page again. I've already tried uninstalling LibreOffice, both using these commands

```
sudo apt remove libreoffice-*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

and from the software centre (where somehow all the applications were still being shown as installed). I then reinstalled LibreOffice 7.6.3.2 from the Ubuntu Software centre, still the same issue.
Hardware info:

```
    System:
  Kernel: 6.1.0-1027-oem x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Framework product: Laptop 13 (AMD Ryzen 7040Series)
    v: A5 serial: <filter>
  Mobo: Framework model: FRANMDCP05 v: A5 serial: <filter> UEFI: INSYDE
    v: 03.03 date: 10/17/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 47.6 Wh (87.5%) condition: 54.4/55.0 Wh (99.0%)
    volts: 17.5 min: 15.4 model: N/A status: Charging
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 7640U w/ Radeon 760M Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 1 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 6 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2075 high: 3500 min/max: 1600/6467 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 1600 2: 1600 3: 3500 4: 3500 5: 1600 6: 1600 7: 1600 8: 1600
    9: 1600 10: 1600 11: 1600 12: 3500 bogomips: 83844
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus-ID: c1:00.0
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution:
    1: 3840x2160~60Hz 2: 2256x1504~60Hz
  OpenGL:
    renderer: GFX1103_R1 (gfx1103_r1 LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.1.0-1027-oem)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: c1:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    driver: snd_pci_ps v: kernel bus-ID: c1:00.5
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: c1:00.6
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.1.0-1027-oem running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: MEDIATEK driver: mt7921e v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.0
  IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB
    driver: r8152 bus-ID: 7-1.3:9
  IF: enx4467522e89d7 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: MediaTek Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-5:5
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 199.74 GiB (21.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WD BLACK SN850X 1000GB
    size: 931.51 GiB temp: 40.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 911.78 GiB used: 199.42 GiB (21.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1
    mapped: vgubuntu-root
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.61 GiB used: 285.3 MiB (17.3%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 40.6 MiB (7.9%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 1.91 GiB used: 3 MiB (0.2%)
    dev: /dev/dm-2 mapped: vgubuntu-swap_1
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 41.8 C mobo: 40.8 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 373 Uptime: 21h 6m Memory: 30.54 GiB used: 4.67 GiB (15.3%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 1855 Shell: Sudo
  v: 1.9.9 inxi: 3.3.13
```

I'm new in switching over to Linux, advice is appreciated!

Comment: v7.6.3.2 is the snap version of LO. The command you used to uninstall was for the deb version. To remove a snap use `sudo snap remove package_name` not `sudo apt remove....`

Comment: "*it causes an automatic logout*:"  That seems the description of a *desktop crash*. Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `ls -lah /var/crash`. That will show us the names of all the .crash files that your system has generated.

Comment: Unable to duplicate: In my 22.04 test environment, both Snap and Deb packages of LibreOffice terminate properly without any crashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to do the opposite i.e. uninstall it from SNAP and install it from APT ... There is a similar issue in LibreOffice reported [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/libreoffice-causes-me-to-log-out-forcefully/81445) although for a slightly earlier version and in other places as well ... Depending on the package maintainer/packager, that issue might not be fixed yet in a certain packaging system or might haven't been introduced yet to another packaging system.

So, you might want, for the time being, to uninstall the snap version from the software center as you did or from the terminal with:

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice
```

... then install the DEB version from APT with:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

... that should work fine as I haven't experienced that issue in the recent DEB versions yet.

If that doesn't work, then you might want to run LibreOffice in safe mode with:

```
libreoffice --safe-mode
```

... where you'll be presented with several troubleshooting/fixing options including restoring configuration/extensions to last known working state, managing extensions and resetting to factory settings among others.

Comment: to confirm, my instance of the DEB version (7.3.7.2) is working fine too without the OPs issue in the snap version.

Comment: The DEB version is working fine, thank you!